# System.Data.SQLite.dll isn't found trying to add a reference

Tags: c#, datagridview, sqlite

(Beginner level) 
I have a DB in SQLite3. 
I would like to populate a DataGridView by data from the DB. 
Currently I'm at the first phase to create a connection/using.

Also, when I add this: `using System.Data.SQLite;` I get an error: 
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'SQLite' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

[In this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0hL5sGkUSA) it guides to add System.Data.SQLite.dll as reference - in folder Program Files (x86) should appear System.Data.Sqlite, but the folder does not exist. The dll file cannot be found, I searched for it also in the Reference Manager Browse.
(Thanks in advance)

Comment: http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/

Answer (score 1):

First Add With Nuget Syste.Data.SqLite.
or run the command in the **Package Manager Console**

```
Install-Package System.Data.SQLite
```

Then right click on your **project references**, an select **add reference**.
Select Under **Assemblies**, **Framework**.

Then left click on **System.Data.SQLite**.

This will add **Mono.Data.SqLite** to your reference.

So type in your code

`using Mono.Data.Sqlite;`

This reference is of the same use case as System.Data.SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the assembly with NuGet. Install [System.Data.SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite).

> To install System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64), run the following command in the [Package Manager Console](https://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console)
>
> ```
> Install-Package System.Data.SQLite
> ```